# Importing a SSL certificate into a Java Keystore via a pfx file

Tags: java, ssl, iis, pfx, jks

I've a requirement where I need to `import a SSL Certificate` into `java keystore`.
Basically, I'm new to this SSL and Java.
I'm from dotnet background, so its quiet complicated doing these things.

Things I've done :

Generated a `pfx` certificate from **IIS**.
Followed this link from [here](http://jackstromberg.com/2013/05/importing-a-ssl-certificate-into-a-java-keystore-via-a-pkcs12-file/) and navigated to the `java bin folder` and `created a new keystore` by following command.

```
keytool -genkey -alias customcertificate.pfx -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore customkeystore
```

I've given the same password for this command, like the password used for pfx generated file.

After that, I've given all the details it asked and the keystore was created.

Now in the second step, I've `emptied the keystore` as the tutorial said.

```
keytool -delete -alias customcertificate -keystore customkeystore
```

I've also tested with this command that nothing is in keystore

```
keytool -v -list -keystore customkeystore
```

Now in the third step, I got a little confused with the **JKS file generation**.

The command is this way :

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore customcertificate.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore customkeystore -deststoretype JKS
```

I've entered both source and destination passwords, and I was confused where the `JKS file would be saved`.

Do I need to create a `empty file` with JKS extension and then given the path at the importing command after **destkeystore**?

Can anyone, please go through the link and guide me the correct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

The response after the last step is : **Entry for alias le-*******-******-*****-**** successfully imported.
Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or
cancelled
[Storing hivemqkeystore]**

Comment: this comment doesn't really answer your question, but just want to say that the java keystores are a nightmare.  I've spent many days fixing bugs with them and trying to get them to work properly.  If you use SSLMate, it just gives you a working keystore that you can download, and so you don't have to do anything.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

THe keystore file will be generated at location at which above command was entered. For e.g. above command was entered at C:\somedir\ then the keystore.jks will be at C:somedir\keystore.jks

Hope this helps !